# Calling _helpers.tpl method/template from .Values.yaml file

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I have two variables defined in helm chart's .Values.yaml file.

var1: false
var2: "test"

I would like to reset the value of var2 based on value of var1 as:
if(var1 eq true)
var2="retest"
end

How is it possible in helm chart?

I have tried different methods but with no success

```
`
{{/*
Return var2
*/}}
 {{- define "testFunction.setVar2" }}
 {{- if .Values.var1 }}
 {{- .Values.var1 | default ("retest") -}} 
 {{- end }}     
 {{- end }}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, because `values.yaml` is not executed, you can see it more like a some values which are filled into template files. That means that you cannot have any conditions or operations inside `values.yaml`.

That leaves you with the following options:

- Use some custom script before executing the `helm` command which will "prepare" the `values.yaml` file for you
- Move this condition to the `templates/*` files

Comment: Can i create a _helpers.tpl method and call from .Values.yaml file?
If so, do we have an example?

Comment: No, you can't call anything from `values.yaml`.